# Combine IFERROR and roundup in one formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

How can I combine an IFERROR formula with an roundup formula (but I need to round up 2 places)?  I have tried this but it did not work:

```
=IFERROR(A167/B167,0)ROUNDUP(A167/B167,2)
```

Comment: It is not clear how you want them to be combined. Please explain what you want and what you have tried; `ROUNDUP()` does not generally return an error.

Comment: I have try this: =IFERROR(A167/B167,0)ROUNDUP(A167/B167,2) but it did not work. How can I combine this together?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just abut two functions as you have done: they must always have some sort of operator between them.

If your formula is `ROUNDUP(A167/B167,2)` and this is generating an error, then it doesn't make sense to combine an invalid value with any other.

What you need is:

```
=IFERROR(ROUNDUP(A167/B167,2),0)
```

This assumes, as you seem to imply, that you want zero as the value substituted for an error (presumably `B167` being zero), though it does not strike me as a good value to use instead of infinity. If there is no error, `IFERROR()` simply returns its first parameter, the calculation result.

So, for any **Expression** which may return an error, an alternative value may be substituted with `IFERROR(Expression, Substitution)`. This need not be of the same type as the expression, so, for example, you can substitute a text string when a numeric calculation is invalid.